# PHP exception custom message

Tags: php, exception

I have an abstract class that wraps PHP exception:

```
abstract class MyException extends Exception
{

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {   
        parent::__construct($message, (int) $code, $previous);
    }
}
```

Then I have other classes like:

```
class UserException extends MyException
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return parent::getMessage();
    }
}
```

When try throw an error doing `throw new UserException('User does not exist');`

It doesn't only show the message I defined.  It shows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught User does not exist thrown in
>   \path\ClassTest.php on line 69

How do I get rid of the "Fatal error: Uncaught..." portion?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

I've found the answer, using `set_exception_handler()` will override uncaught exceptions.  And allow to provide a callback function

Comment: The code you posted is pretty much irrelevant. Are you including try and catch? Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp). Also, google the error message.

Comment: do you have try/catch around the portion you need it?

Comment: You are _throwing_ and not _catching_, so it is _uncaught_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fatal error" part is generated because the exception is thrown outside a try-catch statement, and is finally caught by the php error handler. Uncaught exceptions are always fatal.

Try surrounding the code that generates the exception with a try-catch statement like:

```
try{
    $foo->bar();
catch(UserException $ex){
    // Do something with the exception.
}
```

Alternately you could make your own error handler --> [Linky](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

But the try-catch approach is the "correct" way to do it.